# Advantages of Ultimate Thread group over normal thread group in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, jmeter-plugins, threadgroup

Why do we use Ultimate thread group and what are its advantages over the normal one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Advantages are clearly described here:

- http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/UltimateThreadGroup/

To recap:

- infinite number of schedule records
- separate ramp-up time, shutdown time, flight time for each shedule record
- trustworthy load preview graph